# .selected not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari

I have a form where, if the user selects "married" from a drop down list, some text fields will be displayed asking for their spouse's information. Everything works fine in Firefox and IE, but Safari is giving me trouble.

Here is the HTML:

```
<ul>
<li>
              <label for="maritalStatus">Marital Status</label><br/>
              <select name="maritalStatus" id="maritalStatus" tabindex="80">
                <option name="Single" id="Single" value="Single" selected="selected" onClick="imSingle()">Single</option>

                <option id="Married" name="Married" value="Married" onClick="imMarried()">Married</option>

              </select>
            </li>

<li id="spouseFullName">
              <label for="spouseFullName">Spouse Full Name</label><br/>
              <input type="text" name="Spouse Full Name" id="spouseFullNameField" onchange="spouseName()" tabindex="90"/>
            </li>
            <li id="spouseDOB">
              <label for="spouseDOB">Spouse Date of Birth</label><br/>
              <input type="text" name="Spouse DOB" id="spouseDOB" tabindex="100" />
            </li>
            <li id="spouseOccupation">
              <label for="spouseOccupation">Spouse Occupation</label><br/>
              <input type="text" name="Spouse Occupation" id="spouseOccupation" tabindex="101" />
            </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
document.getElementById("spouseFullName").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("spouseDOB").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("spouseOccupation").style.display = "none";

function imMarried() {
    if (document.getElementById('Married').selected){
        document.getElementById("spouseFullName").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("spouseDOB").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("spouseOccupation").style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

I do have javascript enabled.

Comment: i think there is wrong markup. Only `<select>` have `name` and `id` attribute not the `<option>` .  and two siblings `<option>` have different `name` and `id` confuse me

Comment: If I remove the name and id from the <option> tag, how would I would I write the javascript to display the spouse text fields? Just remove the if statement and only display the spouse fields when the function is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

has to be

```
function imMarried() {
    var maritalStat = document.getElementById('maritalStatus');
    if (maritalStat.options[maritalStat.selectedIndex] && maritalStat.options[maritalStat.selectedIndex].value=="Married") {
        document.getElementById("spouseFullName").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("spouseDOB").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("spouseOccupation").style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

and also add onchange trigger to select and remove onclick from option, i.e.:

```
<select name="maritalStatus" id="maritalStatus" tabindex="80" onchange="imMarried()">
...
<option id="Married" name="Married" value="Married">Married</option>
```

Comment: I updated the javascript and it works fine in Firefox, but still not working in Safari. Were you able to get it to work in Safari?

Comment: No, I have not tested it. Try if (maritalStat.options[maritalStat.selectedIndex] && maritalStat.options[maritalStat.selectedIndex].value=="Married") {...

Comment: Plugged it in and it's the same thing... Firefox works, Safari does not... =(

Comment: I do like how you are getting the value instead of the Id. I'm going to change my code to your suggestion. This will allow me to get rid of the name and id values on my <option> tag that diEcho spoke of... Both of your answers are useful, but I have to have 15 point to mark it as useful.

Comment: that is cool. i understand. you just need to remember that option tag does not fire any events. select fires onchange.

Comment: Adding the onchange made it work in safari and firefox!!!
Thank you for all of your help!!!